# Mariadb JSON iso 8601 timestamp as datetime

Tags: json, mariadb

I am trying to convert a json timestamp as `datetime` in MariaDB but running into issues. I am extracting the json values using `JSON_VALUE` and have tried converting the date using `STR_TO_DATE` which returns null (I'm guessing because of the T and Z in the timestamp).

What the data looks like in the table:

```
'{\"Information\":{\"timestamp\":\"2022-05-03T14:50:06.782Z\",\"Name\":\"Organization"}}
```

Datetime format: ISO 86071
Example: 2023-05-10T10:32:01Z

Query:

```
SELECT
  STR_TO_DATE(JSON_VALUE(generalinfo, '$.Information.timestamp'), "%y-%m-%d, %T") AS "datetime",
  JSON_VALUE(generalinfo, '$.Information.Name') AS Name,
FROM rawjson
GROUP by Name
ORDER BY datetime
```

That query returns NULL in the datetime field. How do I format the timestamp to remove t and z from the json data and have the date displayed as Year Month date Time (2023 05 10 11:00:00)

Comment: what is a "json timestamp"?  show an example of what is in rawjson.generalinfo

Comment: maybe you just mean to be using date_format, not str_to_date which is for converting the other direction?

Comment: here is how the data looks in the table:

'{\"GeneralInfo\":{\"startTime\":\"2022-05-03T14:50:06.782Z\",\"endTime\":\"2023-05-03T14:51:02.242Z\",\"Name\":\"Organization"}

Comment: please edit your question to include that, and include what output you want for that row

Comment: DATE_FORMAT Also returns null

Comment: Where does your Information/ timestamp come from?  Your example has neither

Comment: metrics are sent from several VMs to an endpoint that writes them to the database once an hour.

Comment: I'm saying you are looking for json like `{"Information":{"timestamp":"2022-05-03T14:50:06.782Z","Name":"Organization"}}` but that's not what your json data is.  why are you doing `$.Information.timestamp`?

Comment: I see what you mean, I fixed that in the data output, was a typo. I THINK I figured this out, posting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No need for regexp. It's just the format that is wrong:

`select STR_TO_DATE( '2012-06-25T20:05:13Z', '%Y-%m-%d %T');` returns null

`select STR_TO_DATE( '2022-05-03T14:50:06.782Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s');` will return appropriate result.

so in your case :

```
STR_TO_DATE(JSON_VALUE(generalinfo, '$.Information.timestamp'), '%Y-%m-%d %T') AS "datetime"
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little more experimentation, I figured this one out. It's a little messy but it works, If there's a better way to do this, I am all ears. I added a `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove the T and Z characters from the timestamp, then wrapped that into `STR_TO_DATE`.

```
STR_TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_VALUE(generalinfo, '$.Information.timestamp'), '[A-Z]',' '), '%Y-%m-%d %T') AS "datetime"
```